# Twitter Bootstrap Menu and Accordion for a phones browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This is probably a stupid question. Is it possible to dictate in twitter bootstrap that a horizontal drop down menu, be displayed as a vertical accordian. I can see that I can hide and display elements.

Comment: put that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Course it can doesn't matter if a its a menu/list/whatever: check out the "accordion-group" or as its called in the Docs [Collapse](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse).